# NodeJs reload data from file to view

Tags: node.js, express

My app is fetching data from external file and display it on my ejs view. User can change data by post method. Then it should be saved and displayed immediately on the view. However new data is displayed only after second click on form submit. Not first.

How can I change it?

```
var info;

fetchTag();

function fetchTag()
{   
   fs.readFile('tag.js','utf8',function(err,data){
    if(err){return console.log(err)};
    info = data;    
   });
}

router.get('/',function(req,res){
  res.render('index',{tag: info});
});

router.post('/tag',function(req,res){
   fs.writeFile('tag.js',req.body.tag);

   fetchTag();
   res.redirect('/');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`fs.writeFile()` is an asynchronous function. This means that it isn't finished running before your `.post()` route calls fetchTag.

Then, because your `fethcTag()` function is also asynchronous, it won't finish until after you redirect back to your get route. Try making `fetchTag()` promise based.

```
function fetchTag() { 

   return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
       fs.readFile('tag.js','utf8',function(err,data){
            if(err){
              reject(err)
            } else {
              info = data;
              resolve(info);
            }
       });
   });
}
router.post('/tag',function(req,res){

    fs.writeFile('tag.js', req.body.tag, (err) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log('The file has been saved!');

     fetchTag().then((info)=>{
        res.redirect('/');
     }).catch((err)=>throw err);
});
```

If you go this route, and I think it would be better, you can change the way you handle `info` and rendering your page.

Comment: The only other problem you will have here is the fact that you called your file `tag.js` and not `tag.txt` or `tag.json`. What is the rationale there?